# Copying ranges with formatting from source to destination workbook using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to copy ranges with formatting from one workbook to another. The destination workbook is a template in which I want specific cells to be populated with formatting (fill color, text color etc.)

The code I have is able to copy values but not source formatting. What can I add to below code to achieve that

```
import openpyxl

# Prepare the spreadsheets to copy from and paste too.

# File to be copied
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("T1.xlsx")  # Add file name
sheet = wb["Traffic Sheet"]  # Add Sheet name

# File to be pasted into
template = openpyxl.load_workbook("T1_Template.xlsx")  # Add file name
temp_sheet = template["Traffic Sheet"] # Add Sheet name


# Copy range of cells as a nested list
# Takes: start cell, end cell, and sheet you want to copy from.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    # Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow, endRow + 1, 1):
        # Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol, endCol + 1, 1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
        # Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected


# Paste range
# Paste data from copyRange into template sheet
def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving, copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow, endRow + 1, 1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol, endCol + 1, 1):
            sheetReceiving.cell(row=i, column=j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1


def createData():
    print("Processing...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(4, 4, 6, 6, sheet)  # Change the 4 number values
    pastingRange = pasteRange(4, 4, 6, 6, temp_sheet, selectedRange)  # Change the 4 number values
    # You can save the template as another file to create a new file here too.s
    template.save("T1_Template.xlsx")
    print("Range copied and pasted!")

createData()
```

Comment: The documentation has a section on copying formatting. Hopefully this helps: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html